# KeyboardOverlapp plugin doesn't work on my iOS app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, plugins

I'm using plugin Xam.Plugins.Forms.KeyboardOverlap, but it seems that it doesn't work on my solution.

I added `KeyboardOverlapRenderer.Init()` in my appDelegate init.

I'm using 1.0.0.4 version of the NuGet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Keyboard Plugin in iOS, I recommend **Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager** . Which is **IQKeyboardManager** binding for Unified Xamarin.iOS .

You just need to init it in your iOS project in forms and call the following code in AppDelegate.cs

```
Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager.SharedManager.EnableAutoToolbar = true;
Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager.SharedManager.ShouldResignOnTouchOutside = true;
Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager.SharedManager.ShouldToolbarUsesTextFieldTintColor = true;
Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager.SharedManager.KeyboardDistanceFromTextField = 300f;
```

For more details you could check [Github Project Site](https://github.com/TheEightBot/Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager) .

Comment: it works. Just for notice, I didnt downvoated you, someone else has. Can you provide me an example for Android too?

Comment: So this is the nuget only for ios? is there something similar for android?

Comment: In Android the keyboard should Overlap auto , you could have a test :)

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT how you mean auto?  I added ios nuget only

Comment: In Android the keyboard will overlay in default . You don't need to use some plugin .Did you  have a try ?

Comment: Lucas Zhang is correct - on Android it is built-in. As soon as you gain focus on a focusable element, the view scrolls itself to adjust it. It is a good approach to wrap your content (Entries, Labels, etc) inside a ScrollView, so that the user can scroll through the form on demand. By default, if you have many entries and select one from the middle, you cannot scroll down to reveal the next one.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend the package that Lucas Zhang has mentioned, since it hasn't been updated for 3 years now. Also, there doesn't seem to be any movement in the GitHub repo as well. You can see in their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/TheEightBot/Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager) that it is pretty much left to be as is. There are some issues with iOS 13 and iPhone X+. Also, they have been planning to upgrade it for 2 years now, but to no success. See this in the [issues](https://github.com/TheEightBot/Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager/issues/12).

If I would recommend a different package, it will be [this one](https://github.com/eman1986/Hackiftekhar.IQKeyboardManager.Xamarin). It is the again a *binding* for **IQKeyboardManager**, but this time it is a fork of the repo and it is being maintained better than the original one. The current version is **6.5.5** and the last commit was **3 monts ago**. 
You can get the NuGet link [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hackiftekhar.IQKeyboardManager.Xamarin/).

So, if you are going to choose a package, pick this one, as it has better support.

Comment: I really don't understand the downvotes. The Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager NuGet package hasn't been updated for 3 years. You can see all of the bug that have been fixed during that time in the official project's repo: https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/releases?after=v6.3.0
None of the last fixes have been in this NuGet package. A better package would be Hackiftekhar.IQKeyboardManager.Xamarin since it keeps the versions up-to-date and is a fork of the aforementioned package. But okay - if you want, use the unsupported one. Just be careful with any hidden issues that will arrise...

Comment: How do you use this with Xamarin Forms?

Comment: Aah figured it out. IQKeyboardManager.SharedManager().Enable = true; (in FinishedLaunching).